# Has anyone seen Control.SendToFront?

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0

Hello I want to send a control to the front, but the only method I find in the Control class related to that is `SendToBack()`.

Does anyone knows why there isn't a method `SendToFront`, is there a reason or someone just forgot to add it?
Then so, how can I send my control to the front of the z-order?

Thank you,
Rodrigo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [BringToFront](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I think I got lost in translation :-)